# How to run Apache Storm in Single Node on Windows OS

Tags: streaming, apache-storm, bigdata

How to run Apache Storm in Single Node on Windows OS? Can anyone provide a link for that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Install Java**

Download and install a JDK (Storm works with both Oracle and OpenJDK 6/7). For this setup I used JDK 7 from Oracle.

I installed Java in:

```
C:\Java\jdk1.7.0_45\
```

**Install Python**

To test the installation, we’ll be deploying the “word count” sample from the storm-starter project which uses a multi-lang bolt written in python. I used python 2.7.6 which can be downloaded here.

I installed python in:

```
C:\Python27\
```

**Install and Run Zookeeper**

Download Apache Zookeeper 3.3.6 and extract it. Configure and run Zookeeper with the following commands:

```
> cd zookeeper-3.3.6
> copy conf\zoo_sample.cfg conf\zoo.cfg
> .\bin\zkServer.cmd
```

**Install Storm**

The changes that allow Storm to run seamlessly on Windows have not been officially released yet, but you can download a build with those changes incorporated here.

(Source branch for that build can be found here).

Extract that file to the location of your choice. I chose C:.

**Configure Environment Variables**

On Windows Storm requires the STORM_HOME and JAVA_HOME environment variables to be set, as well as some additions to the PATH variable:

```
JAVA_HOME:
C:\Java\jdk1.7.0_45\

STORM_HOME:
C:\storm-0.9.1-incubating-SNAPSHOT-12182013\

PATH: (add)
%STORM_HOME%\bin;%JAVA_HOME%\bin;C:\Python27;C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\;C:\Python27\Scripts\;

PATHEXT: (add)
.PY
```

Start Nimbus, Supervisor, and Storm UI Daemons

For each deamon open a separate command prompt.

**Nimbus**

> cd %STORM_HOME%
>   storm nimbus
>   Supervisor
>
> cd %STORM_HOME%
>   storm supervisor
>   Storm UI
>
> cd %STORM_HOME%
>   storm ui
>   Verify that Storm is running by opening http://localhost:8080/ in a browser.

Deploy the “Word Count” Topology

Either build the storm-starter project from source, or download a pre-built jar

Deploy the Word Count topology to your local cluster with the storm jar command:

> storm jar storm-starter-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar storm.starter.WordCountTopology WordCount -c nimbus.host=localhost